# Xserver problems

Tags: xorg, lightdm, xserver

using ubuntu 14.04 and want to configure xserver manually. 
I stopped lightdm and then executed `X -configure`
It created an xorg.conf.new and i just movd it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf (created a new file, cause there were no xorg.conf). 
Then i started lightdm again. Login screen appeared. After log-in attempt it drops me to login screen again. X server restarts. How i can get things back now? Deleting xorg.conf doesnt help. Why this actually happens?
Ask for logs you may need to understand the prob.

Answer (score 0):

> After log-in attempt it drops me to login screen again

So you installed the X server and a login manager. But did you instal a desktop/window manager? Like Metacity, Openbox, etc.?

To resolve your problem:

1. See if you can choose a desktop/window manager in lightdm.
2. If not, try to install one like `apt-get install fluxbox` or so.
3. If still not working, post the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after you tried again.

HTH